# The following packages have unmet dependencies when uninstall gcc

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, gcc

I am installing opencv 2.4.5 but it causes the same error as in this page http://answers.opencv.org/question/21715/usrincludehost_configh822-error-error-unsupported-gnu-version-gcc-47-and-up-are-not-supported/. In order to fix it, we have to install gcc 4.6 instead of 4.7 or higher. But when I remove gcc 4.6 by "sudo apt-get remove .." or "autoremove", an error appears like this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dkms : Depends: gcc but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This is my gcc's version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? it shouldn't be necessary to remove gcc-4.7 in order to install gcc-4.6

Comment: I've finished rewrite my question

Comment: If `gcc-4.7` is the default version for your system (i.e. it is the direct dependent of package `gcc`) then I suggest you leave it installed and specify `gcc-4.6` explicitly where required e.g. (in the case of `cmake` for example) `-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-4.6`

Comment: Where do we reconfigure this cmake command ?

Comment: @LeeDat it would just be added to whatever cmake command you are running e.g. `cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-4.6 -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-4.6 ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can have as many gcc, g++ versions as you want, installed at the same time.

2) Tell cmake to use a specific compiler: `CC=gcc-4.6 CXX=g++-4.6 cmake ../`

Comment: In my shell script "opencv2-4-5.sh" file that runs to install opencv, there's a line of command cmake. So is it to be replaced by your command cmake ?

Comment: Just add the new text to the script `CC=gcc-4.6 CXX=g++-4.6 cmake [option] [option] [option] ..`